# Node application failing to come up from Jenkins

Tags: node.js, angular, jenkins, ansible

I have an ansible file which runs via Jenkins

```
  shell: 'unzip -o p.zip'
  args:
    chdir: '/home/ec2-user/'
- pause: seconds=10
- name:  install eslint
  shell: 'npm install -g eslint --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root'
  args:
    chdir: '/home/ec2-user/'
- name:  remove node-sass
  shell: 'npm uninstall --save-dev node-sass'
  args:
    chdir: '/home/ec2-user/'
- name:  install node-sass
  shell: 'npm install --save-dev node-sass'
  args:
    chdir: '/home/ec2-user/'
  failed_when: false
- pause: seconds=10
- name:  start ng serve
  shell: 'ng serve --port 4401 --host 0.0.0.0 --verbose &'
  args:
    chdir: '/home/ec2-user/'
```

But the application is getting killed.
when I run the last command manually it brings up the service:--`ng serve --port 4401 --host 0.0.0.0 --verbose &`

The same command is failing via ansible

Comment: Are there any errors? Which step of the playbook is it failing?

Comment: no errors it runs successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below change works
`shell: 'nohup ng serve --port 4401 --host 0.0.0.0 > nohup.out 2>&1 &'`